# onBackPressed - avoid destroying activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have two activities - activity A starts activity B. Then activity B loads some stuff from database, and visualizes the data. It takes some time (5-10sec) to fully initialize all the stuff in B.

My problem is that if I press back button in B, it destroys B activity (calls onDestroy) and returns to activity A. I still want to return to activity A, but **without destroying B**, because if I launch B again, I have to wait again before it does all the stuff (which is annoying). Is this possible somehow?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Fragment`s, but what you really want to do is cache the information. Otherwise you'll reload on device rotation anyways (unless you use `Fragment`s and `setRetainInstance` to true, but this can cause other headaches).

I would use a `CursorLoader` on Activity B's `onCreate`. `onLoadFinished` you cache the result and setup your UI. On subsequent loads the results are cached and you forego the loader. What's more, using the `CursorLoader` will alert you if the underlying database results change.

Comment: That's the right answer, as the one of @Orabîg, you will never be able to ask android to keep an activity alive. Android can garbage collect whatever activity when it is under memory pressure.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Fragments. I know I can't force android not to kill the activity. I just expect the average case when you go back to A and a few minutes after you want to go to B again...

Comment: Again, fragments may not even work and if they do they come with some subtleties that you should be well aware of. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29
I would much rather recommend you look into Loaders.

Comment: Also you need to handle screen orientation. Even in that situation activity is destroyed and recreated.

Comment: @Raghunandan: Thanks, I know about that. But I don't expect orientation to change very often, I'm concerned about the average cases..

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not see the problem from the right point of view.

I'd say that you can't prevent B to be destroyed if Android wants to (because it's up to it to handle the activities).
However, you have the choice to move all the long initialisation in a third class which can be persisted all the time. So you should make this init phase independant from your B activity.

I think that putting all this in an attribute of your Application class would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to manage a third class where I would temporarily persist the initialized data, since there are more instances of B with different data (and the data update periodically) so it would be quite complicated...

Comment: Do as you wish, but I think that you won't have many choices. And I don't get where your argument explains that you cannot use an external class. I wish you'll find the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [AndroidFragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use **[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)** to store key-value pairs then use `getSharedPreferences()` to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

When you press back button Activity b is destroyed. It is how android works. I would not try to override the default functionality

Once you get data from data base you can cache then some where and load it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. Check the topic under Saving cache files.